# Why does MetaMask cap the gasLimit for ERC20 transfers?

Tags: metamask, gas-limit

We have found that MetaMask doesn't appear to actually estimate gas for ERC20 transfers as it does for interactions with other contracts.

Here, it appears to `estimateGas` when the interaction is with a contract that is not a token.

- https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/e02f5972be33c2ff56827c25dc2d0e55cae0f695/ui/ducks/send/helpers.js#L133C8-L133C8

Unfortunately, it won't make it that far when it's a token. This seems to test for the "send token" context and returns `GAS_LIMITS.BASE_TOKEN_ESIMATE` instead of proceeding with the estimate to see what actually happens.

- https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/e02f5972be33c2ff56827c25dc2d0e55cae0f695/ui/ducks/send/helpers.js#L55

You may ask, what is `GAS_LIMITS.BASE_TOKEN_ESIMATE`? It's 100,000.

- https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/e02f5972be33c2ff56827c25dc2d0e55cae0f695/shared/constants/gas.ts#L8C2-L8C2

Unless I'm wrong, this means that token transfer logic can't exceed 100,000 gas or MetaMask goes off the rails with insufficient gas, when users accept the default estimate.

Does anyone know the rationale for treating ERC20 contracts as a special species when a gas estimate would be simpler as well as more accurate in some cases?

**UPDATE:**

Example transaction that ran out of gas before completing its own logic because the user accepted the default 100,000 gas suggested by MetaMask.

- https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0x31548bf3b8180d02f6884b9c5a9d7170173237fefc3b72c170928da66e8a14b6

**UPDATE 2:**

There's a pretty nice assessment over here, although the exact mechanism is still elusive. Thanks, Alex. [MetaMask incorrectly estimates 100,000 gas for ERC20 transfer. Why?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152813/metamask-incorrectly-estimates-100-000-gas-for-erc20-transfer-why/153308#153308)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is stated in the comment in your second link.

```
  // If no to address is provided, we cannot generate the token transfer
  // hexData. hexData in a transaction largely dictates how much gas will
  // be consumed by a transaction. We must use our best guess, which is
  // represented in the gas shared constants.
```

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/e02f5972be33c2ff56827c25dc2d0e55cae0f695/ui/ducks/send/helpers.js#L57C6-L60C6

Comment: I saw that comment and dismissed it because "if no to address is provided" does not apply. The situation occurs when sending to another wallet. Am I misinterpreting the comment?

Comment: Here is one that simply ran out of gas when the user accepted the default 100,000 that was presented by MetaMask. The contract would determine success or failure if it had enough gas to complete execution of its own logic. https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0x31548bf3b8180d02f6884b9c5a9d7170173237fefc3b72c170928da66e8a14b6

Comment: I'm not satisfied with the answers and remain on the hunt for a full understanding and course of action. I awarded the bounty to be a good sport. I'll be a good sport to others who chime in on the related question.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/153378/metamask-doesnt-catch-erc20-reverts