# MetaMask doesn't catch ERC20 reverts

Tags: metamask, infura, revert

When MetaMask interacts with most contracts, it seems to catch reverts and warn the user. However, when the user interacts with an ERC20 contract's `transfer` function, MetaMask does not catch a revert. It appears to rely instead on its user balance checks.

In the case that the ERC20 reverts MetaMask will return a gas estimate of 100,000 and allow the user to send the transaction without warning.

[image]

Is this a MetaMask bug or are we missing something?

In this example, the ERC20 transfer is interrupted by internal logic - a very simple revert. For testing purposes, you can set it to succeed or fail at will. For tester convenience, you can mint tokens, up to 1 (e18) at a time.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.14;

import { ERC20 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract PickyERC20 is ERC20 {

    // uint256 private wastefulValue;
    bool public succeed;

    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol)
        ERC20(name, symbol) 
    { }

    function transfer (
        address receiver, 
        uint256 amount
    ) 
        public 
        override(ERC20) 
        returns (bool) 
    {
        require (succeed, "This transaction was meant to fail");
        return ERC20.transfer(receiver, amount);
    }
    function setSucceed (bool succeed_) public  {
        succeed = succeed_;
    }

    function mint(uint256 amount) public {
        require(amount < 1e18, "easy does it"); // prevent overflow
        _mint(msg.sender, amount);
    }

}
```

You can find the contract code verified on Goerli.

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x27F02912D6be3520feF4D1b657f55188B5440788#code

Everything is fine when `succeed == true`. When `succeed == false`, MetaMask will raise 100,000 gas and encourage the user to proceed. This seems incorrect and new. We need to good explanation and, ideally, a course of action. This could include a PR for MetaMask if we can pinpoint the logic error.

There's interesting stuff going on here, but the search is by no means limited to this. Starting point to help any kind souls who want to chime in: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/e02f5972be33c2ff56827c25dc2d0e55cae0f695/ui/ducks/send/send.js

Answer (score 1):

This is the MetaMask feature/bug. To understand what happens: MetaMask has the built-in page for sending tokens: [send.js](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/861c30de299cfe5d3c43c043a588ace37e1d0a6a/ui/ducks/send/send.js) and this is a separate page comparing to submitting the raw transaction from a dApps page. The logic flow is also different - they don't handle the estimation errors, so they are silently swallowed: [send.js#L1551](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/861c30de299cfe5d3c43c043a588ace37e1d0a6a/ui/ducks/send/send.js#L1551).

The standard transaction controller handles the errors for gas estimation as expected, but I would also say not perfectly - they don't show what exactly went wrong, but at least show the error warning that the estimation failed, so the transaction could fail: [confirm-transaction-base.component.js#L454](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/861c30de299cfe5d3c43c043a588ace37e1d0a6a/ui/pages/confirm-transaction-base/confirm-transaction-base.component.js#L454)

You can try manually executing the `transfer` method on etherscan: [0x27F02912D6be3520feF4D1b657f55188B5440788#writeContract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x27F02912D6be3520feF4D1b657f55188B5440788#writeContract) by connecting the account and writing the `transfer` method. You will notice, that the error is shown regarding the failed gas estimation.

One should create an issue in the Metamask repository to find out if this is the desired behavior for sending a token via MetaMask UI - *to proceed no matter what*, or if the team has forgotten to notify the user, that the gas estimation failed, and so will the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for that. Super helpful.

Comment: Just opened an issue https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/20515 but not sure how the team handles the issues, there are already 1.8K of the opened issues )